# Accuracy Dropped suddenly after certain epoch (Classification using EfficientNet)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

So I have been training EfficientNet for a classification task. I used EfficientNet-B2 model with a batch size of 64 and a learning rate 0.0001.

I was able to get good accuracy and loss while gradually increasing batch size and decreasing the learning rate. But when I just used lr 0.0001 and let the model run, I found the accuracy dropping significantly after 26th epoch while the loss curve was following the usual curve.

I have found a good model but just wanted to know what might be the reason for the accuracy behaving like that in the graph.

[image: Model Training curver]